# Chosing the name of the output yaml file

Tags: python, yaml

I have a script that save data into a yaml format, and I obtain around 5000 files.

The data come from a csv file, and one of those date, is a name, I would like to name my output yaml files from the names in the csv file (column 2).

Here is what I have

```
import csv
import ruamel.yaml
from csv import reader
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True

with open('config.yaml') as yml:
    doc = yaml.load(yml)

with open('params.csv') as f:
    for i, data in enumerate(reader(f)):
        doc['components']['star']['init'][0]['values']['logg'] = data[6]
        with open(f'config-{i}.yaml', 'w') as out:
            yaml.dump(doc, out)
```

The output files are then named `config-0.yaml, config-1.yaml.......` but I would like their name to come from my csv file whoch is construct like this:

```
2, ngc6397id000000002jd2456871p6250f000.fits, 6304.19055182, 97.72410249, ....
7, ngc6397id000000007jd2456871p6250f000.fits, 6177.99367633, 27.03483789, ....
```

I'd like to have as output like:

```
ngc6397id000000002jd2456871p6250f000.yaml, ngc6397id000000007jd2456871p6250f000.yaml....
```

But I can't find a way to name my yaml files in consequence, can you help ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to get first part of second row value:

```
with open('params.csv') as f:
    for i, data in enumerate(reader(f)):
        doc['components']['star']['init'][0]['values']['logg'] = data[6]
        filename = data[1].split(".")[0]  
        with open(f'{filename}.yaml', 'w') as out:
            yaml.dump(doc, out)
```

Comment: Yes ! Thank you !! I've been looking forever and nothing worked ! Easy and simple